# api response contains escape characters

Tags: node.js, json, sails.js

I am getting value from API response as below

```
{
        "ORG_ID":"165",
        "DEPOT_NAME":"Pesto",
        "DEPOT_SHORT_NAME":"PSD",
        "PROD_ID":"709492",
        "DESCRIPTION":"EX CL (2X14) U17\SH36\5",
        "PRICE":"3708.55",
        "STOCK":"2"
},
```

now when I am parsing it in json like json.parse(response) it cashes the app.. error is below:

```
undefined:11
        "DESCRIPTION":"EXELON HGC 4.5MG (2X14) U17\SH36\5",
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 296
```

What should I do to get rid of these escapes.

though I need the same values I don't want to change any value or remove these slashes.

Comment: Hope comma is not there in response?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special characters before parsing the jSON.

In this case for it to be valid it should be:

```
{
        "ORG_ID":"165",
        "DEPOT_NAME":"Pesto",
        "DEPOT_SHORT_NAME":"PSD",
        "PROD_ID":"709492",
        "DESCRIPTION":"EX CL (2X14) U17\\SH36\\5",
        "PRICE":"3708.55",
        "STOCK":"2"
}
```